# Can a ps3 work with a chromebook?

Tags: ps3

I currently have my ps3 slim connected to my chromebook. I'm wondering if it will work, thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish... Connected to your Chromebook for what purpose? Are you trying to use the Chromebooks screen?

Comment: Agree with Broots, please clarify exactly what "working" means in this context.  Even if it won't "work" we may be able to offer alternate solutions that will.  Also, if you *currently* have the two connected... **is** it "working?"  If there's a specific roadblock or error message, tell us as that may shed some light on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Most video *ports* (HDMI included) are usually not bidirectional. The HDMI port on a Chromebook and a PS3 are both OUT, and will not accept incoming video/audio signals.